# what is the JDBC driver class name for mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter

Like `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in the case of `mysql`, what would be the `JDBC` `driver` class for `mongodb`?

In java code, it can be obtained as

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
```

but in the case of `JMeter`, it requires `JDBC` driver class name.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/ Please Refer this.

Comment: The [Unity JDBC](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php) will be your friend.

Comment: Note that the answers suggesting `mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver` are referring to the commercial [Unity JDBC Driver](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php). There is no officially supported JDBC driver for MongoDB. As per the answer from Dmitry T, JMeter 2.10+ supports using the official MongoDB Java driver as an alternative to JDBC.

Answer (score 10):

You can try and use below details as reference

> JDBC Driver class name: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
>
> URL format:jdbc:mongo://<\serverName>/<\databaseName>
>
> e.g. url="jdbc:mongo://ds029847.mongolab.com:29847/tpch";
>
> Con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "dbuser", "dbuser");

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it as Below.

> JDBC Driver class name:  mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver URL format:
>   jdbc:mongo://(serverName)/(databaseName)

For More Details Refer [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/) Link

Answer (score 2):

In JMeter version 2.10 2 new test elements were introduced:

1. [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config)
2. [MongoDB Script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script)

Which can be used for sending requests to MongoDB server as an alternative to JDBC Request Sampler.

In [JMeter version 2.11](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-211-top-5-features-and-updates) built-in MongoDB Java driver has been updated to `mongo-java-driver-2.11.3`

Comment: ...which have been deprecated again in JMeter 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
// To connect to mongodb server
         MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
```