# Add MongoDB as a new source data in SpagoBi studio, can't find the MongoDB driver class name

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, business-intelligence, spagobi

I managed to add my mongo data source under SpagoBi server (version 5.1) but I can't do it under SpagoBI studio(version 5.1) .
I can't find the mongoDB driver under the available list of jdbc driver in SpagoBI studio and when I tried to add it I got those exceptions:

I tried:
to add a new data source -> add a new connection profile -> I chose "generic jdbc"
In the driver class name I tried:

- "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver" like mentionned in this thread [1]
  but it gave me this exception :

  ```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
  ```
- I tried "com.mongodb.Mongo" and it gives me:

  ```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.Mongo cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
  ```

How can I add my MongoDB as a new data source under SpagoBI Studio?

[1] [what is the JDBC driver class name for mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598245/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-class-name-for-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB datasource with SpagoBI. All-In-One-SpagoBI-5.1.0_21012015 and installed the mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar

Following are the datasource configuration details :

Type: jdbc URL : server:port/database User : dbusername Pasword : dbpasword Driver: mongo

User driver name as mongo and place the mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar in lib folder