# Error trying to load driver for generic database configuration in Mule

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, mule, database-connection

I am using Mule 3.6 and would like to use the bulk insert option on the Generic Database Configuration to load data into mongodb 3.0.8.

I have entered the URL as:
jdbc:mongo://localhost:27017/test

and have tried a number of different Mongo and JDBC drivers but keep receiving the message "Test connection failed.  Error trying to load driver..."

How can I configure the Generic Database Connector in Mule to connect to Mongo?

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Is the driver's jar on the classpath?

Comment: It is just a pop up message when I click "Test Connection".  The drivers I have tried, I have selected from the list from the Driver Class Name box on the generic database configuration global element properties.  I have mongo-java-driver and mule-module-mongo jar files in the classpath

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598245/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-class-name-for-mongodb#comment43629844_27598245), there is **no official JDBC driver for MongoDB** but one the suggested alternatives is using [UnityJDBC](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php).

If you decide to follow the **UnityJDBC** approach, then:

1. **Download and install** the driver by executing the following command:

   `java -jar UnityJDBC_Trial_Install.jar`
2. Go to the installation folder and copy `mongodb_unityjdbc_full.jar` to the classpath of your Mule app.

[image]

3. Configure the URL and Driver in the Global Element of your Generic Database component (the values you provided are OK):

   **URL:** `jdbc:mongo://<host>:<port>/<database>`

   **Driver Class Name:** `mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver`

If not, use the [MongoDB Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mongodb-connector) as suggested by @JoostD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MongoDB connector, it should be included in studio.

Otherwise install it from the Anypoint Exchange:

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/#!/mongodb-integration-connector

Also see some example on it:

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/#!/importing-csv-into-mongodb