# Mapping mongodb in dropwizard?

Tags: java, mongodb, dropwizard, odm

I am currently using hibernate in my project, and am using that to push data to SQL. However, that was just as a proof of concept, and in the long term, this project really needs to be running a NoSQL backend.

I've used mongoose with node, but this project is using Java & Dropwizard, is there anything available to me which will enable me to get ODM behavior with these technologies?

I have googled around, and found various github repos, but they seem the be dead project that I have found so far, I am looking for something with a community, and a bit of maturity.

Comment: I believe for this you will likely have to write your own factory that you can reference via the yaml file. That is likely what most of the projects do that you found online. I am not aware of any 3rd party dependencies that do that for you.

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598245/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-class-name-for-mongodb