# Connection with jmeter azure mognodb

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, azure-cosmosdb

Has anyone tried connecting jmeter with azure mongodb. I tried connecting the emulator, but i am not able to connect, not getting any error also. Or any idea if Jmeter supports connection with azure mongodb or not ?

Check azure documentation: It states the connection string should be something like this.

```
mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Meaning: did you try, and get an error? If so: what error? In your question, you include the connection string for the emulator. Do you have the emulator running on your machine? Please edit your question to be more specific, especially around the exact issues you're having. As for Jmeter, I'm not sure there's anything specific (at least, not in your question).

Comment: Hi David, 

i am not getting any error . I am using JMeter View Result Tree Listener, which is not displaying anything if i try to connect

Answer (score 0):

Shankar,

kindly use the JDBC connection configuration Config Element and while using that please refer to the link below, i hope it will work for u.
[StackOverflow JDBC Driver Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598245/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-class-name-for-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Azure MongoDB just like any other MongoDB instance.

1. Click `Connect` button on your [MongoDB Azure Cluster Control Panel](https://cloud.mongodb.com/)

   [image]
2. Click `Connect Your Application`

   [image]
3. Click `Standard Connection String`

   [image]
4. Use generated Connection String (replace `<PASSWORD>` with your actual password) in the [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)'s as the parameter to [MongoClients.create()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoClients.html#create-com.mongodb.ConnectionString-) function

   [image]
5. Check out [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter) article for further steps if required

Comment: What you've shown isn't Azure MongoDB. it's native MongoDB (even if running in Azure). The OP is asking about the MongoDB API of Cosmos DB, which doesn't use the same management tools that you've shown). I suspect there is an issue specific to the connection string format the OP is using, but... not quite enough details in the question (which is why I was asking them about the emulator, etc)